# Delete individual lines/rows with PHP button

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I am trying to do is have a PHP page display the contents  of a MySQL database and and each line it displays, it give me a delete button so I can delete individual rows. I have the code kind of working. The code delete the lines of code, but not the one I select, instead it deletes the last line and not the one I tell it to delete.

Here is a screenshot, I know it does not look pretty, I was going to clean it up after I get the code working.[image]

HTML:

```
    <?php
        // Delete php code
        if(isset($_POST['delete_series']))
        {
            // here comes your delete query: use $_POST['deleteItem'] as your id
            $delete = $_POST['delete_series'];
            $delete_sql = "DELETE FROM `Dropdown_Series` where `id` = '$delete'"; 

            if(mysql_query($delete_sql, $conn))
            {
                echo "Row Deleted </br>";
                echo "$delete";

            };
        }

        //Insert Code
        if(isset($_POST['add_series']))
        {           
            $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO dropdown_series (series) VALUES ('$_POST[add_series]' )";

            if(!mysql_query($insert_sql, $conn))
                {
                    die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                } 

            echo "Series Added <br><br>";

        }

    ?>
    <br />
    <h1>Add New Series Title</h1>

    <h3>Add New: </h3><br />

    <form name = action="add_series.php" method="POST">

    <input type = "text" name = "add_series" required/><br /><br />
    <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

    </form>

    <h3>Current Series: </h3><br />


    <?php
            //Delete button on each result of the rows
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, series FROM Dropdown_Series");     // Run your query

            // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {

                echo $row['series'] . " ";
                echo $row['id'];
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
                echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
                //echo $row['series'] . " ". $row['id'] . "<input type='submit' value='delete'>";
                echo "<br />";

            } 

        echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

Comment: mysql = bad, unsanitized user inputs = crazy. if either of those is unclear do a little research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will result in multiple delete_series inputs - within the same form.

You could create separat forms for each option:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
  echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
  // ...
  echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
  // ...
  echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: ,Awesome it looks like it works, one more question, how can I get the result and the button for delete on the same line, not on separate line?

Comment: That's related to your styles. i guess you configured those to be `display:block` in your css somewhere but you want them to be `display:inline`. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: I checked and I do not see a display:block that would be the issue, could I add a tag like a div tag and set for those results to only display as inline? If so can you please help me with the css? I am still new with CSS

Comment: @Vlad this person IMHO answered the original question and it should be marked as solved. What you're asking here is another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a very quick answer would be

```
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
            echo $row['series'] . " ";
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='delete_series' value=' " . $row['id'] . "' />";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Delete'>";
            //echo $row['series'] . " ". $row['id'] . "<input type='submit' value='delete'>";
            echo "<br />";
            echo "</form>";

        }
```

If I were you I would prefer injecting some javascript in the logic, and perform the Delete request using an ajax call.

you can refer to this tutorial to get more understanding of what I am refering to https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery